# MySQL producing garbage output for simple queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that is very simple, containing four fields:

```
id (autonumbered)
controllerType
onInstructions
offInstructions
```

I loaded the table with data from a CSV file. The file looks like this:

```
10,GK 212-02,,
11,GK 212-02 ex,,
12,GK 212-04,,
13,GK 212-06,,
14,GK 212-06 x 2,,
```

And the query I run looks like this:

```
load data local infile '/home/garfonzo/controllers.csv' into table systems_controller_type fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (id, controllerType, onInstructions, offInstructions);
```

It loads the data into the table with no warnings:

```
Query OK, 42 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 42  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Then, when I run a `select * from systems_controller_type` I get this output:

```
+----+-------------------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | controllerType                | onInstructions | offInstructions |
+----+-------------------------------+----------------+-----------------+
               |                     |                |
               | Plus                |                |
               |ar                   |                |
               |ar exterior          |                |
               |ird                  |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               | ex                  |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               | x 2                 |                |
               |                     |                |
               |06                   |                |
               |                     |                |
               | 06                  |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |el                   |                |
               |troller              |                |
               |                     |                |
               |E-12                 |                |
               |EC-9                 |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |nder (x2)            |                |
               |- 9 station          |                |
               |                     |                |
               |rollers              |                |
               |Modular              |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
               |om Command (I think) |                |
               |lar                  |                |
               |mmand                |                |
               | 04 04 04            |                |
               |                     |                |
               |                     |                |
+----+-------------------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

If I do a `select` for one record, I get this:

```
select * from systems_controller_type where id=3;
+----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | controllerType | onInstructions | offInstructions |
+----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
               |ar    |                |
+----+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea as to what is going on?? Did I do something wrong at the import stage?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following query... (without updating auto increment column - hope you would have set auto increment value while creating the table) ..

load data local infile '/home/garfonzo/controllers.csv' into table systems_controller_type fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (@dummy, controllerType, onInstructions, offInstructions);

Comment: Yes, auto-increment was set when the table was created. Are you saying that perhaps MySQL is getting confused that I'm trying to force a value into a field that should take care of itself (auto-increment)?

Comment: The problem, however, is that I need to maintain specific values for the `id` column. MySQL does support inserting values into an auto-increment column so long as you don't break the uniqueness rule (which I don't)

Comment: to my knowledge Load data ... statement doesn't support this(inserting auto increment values) instead id field to unique..  for changing the auto increment values.. Using (DDL) alter table you can change the auto increment starting value. But not in (DML) while inserting records.